# Space between two buttons mobile site

Tags: php, html, css, button, mobile

I have a problem with buttons when my site switch on mobile version

Html is:

```html
<p style="text-align: right;">
<a class="button btn-primary" href="index.php/reprogrammation/193-bmw"> Retour "Choix de la marque" </a>
</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">
<a class="button btn-primary" href="#">2005 - E8x</a>     
<a class="button btn-primary" href="#">2007 - E8x</a>  
<a class="button btn-primary" href="#">2011 - F2x</a>
</p>

<p><img style="float: right;" src="images/marques/bmw/serie1.png" alt="" width="400" height="150" /></p>
```

CSS is:

```css
.btn-primary {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 2px solid #C01C32;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 8px 24px;
```

Here are two screenshots:

**PC Version**
[image: PC Version]

**Mobile version**
[image: Mobile Version]

Can anyone please tell me how to put a space between this buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.btn-primary {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 2px solid #C01C32;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 8px 24px;
}
```

I suggest using the display inline-block to achieve the desired affect, adjust to preference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks with inline-block and margin:5px

Comment: Just fyi you should write things like that as a comment on the answer ;) Glad to help